# Proof that every three-dimensional Einstein manifold has constant curvature

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In pseudo-Riemannian geometry it is well known that every three-dimensional Einstein manifold has constant curvature. A proof of this is sketched [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2194463/242708).

**Question**. Does anyone know where in the literature I can find a proof of such result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is precisely Proposition 1.120 on p.49 in Besse's "Einstein Manifolds" (I am using the reprint of the 1987 edition, so the numbering may be different in the older edition):

> A 3-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold is Einstein iff it has  constant (sectional) curvature.

Note that the proof is before the proposition.